# D.js specific channel detection

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a system which detects when user gets muted (given a muted role) and then the bot sends a video to `#general`. How could I improve the code so that the bot would detect in which channel the user got muted?

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
  if (!oldMember.roles.cache.get("949798282442473582") && newMember.roles.cache.get("949798282442473582")) {

    client.channels.cache.get("791388060683862066").send({
      files: [{
        attachment: "screenshot/muted.mp4",
        name: "muted.mp4",
      },
      ],
      content: "<@" + newMember.id + ">",
    });
    return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Version of d.js is latest, v14

Comment: You could only detect on what channel the user got muted if your bot muted him else if the role was given manually by someone that's impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to know in which channel the user was muted from the [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate) event. Assuming your bot has a `mute` command, you need to determine the channel in which that command was used in either the [`interactionCreate`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-interactionCreate) or [`messageCreate`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) events, depending on whether you're using slash commands or not. Those events emit [`BaseInteraction`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/BaseInteraction) and [`Message`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message) objects respectively, both of which have a `channel` and `channelId` attribute.

Comment: Ok so no way with `guildMemberUpdate`

Comment: Yeah. If you'd like I can add some example code to my answer.

Comment: Cool, if my answer helped you figure it out, can you mark it as the answer to your question? Thanks.